# How to set tkinter window focus out?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to do make a virtual keyboard using tkinter. Is there any method that allow tkinter window focus out? For example in java we can have `setFocusableWindowState(false)`

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you set this "focus out" parameter? Are you actually asking how to disable a widget so the user can't type or click on it?

Comment: actually, I would like to make a virtual keyboard. Let's say I use it to type in Word doc, the virtual keyboard is always on top but it will not steal the focus of Word doc when I click the button on tkinter window. Sorry, I am not that good at explanation.

Comment: You can't do that with tkinter. If tkinter is accepting events, something will have focus. You can't make a virtual keyboard that will let you type into some other application.

Comment: what about Kivy or other gui tools? can they do it?

Comment: I do not know if any other toolkits can do it or not.

Comment: oh,i see. Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, it's definitely possible to make a virtual keyboard via Python+Tkinter. It's been forever since I've done anything like that, but I have.

Comment: @WayneWerner: it's possible to make a keyboard, but I think it's impossible to make the keyboard be useful in other non-tkinter applications such as Word. At least, not without some platform-specific hacks.

Comment: Oh, for certain. One could use https://github.com/PyUserInput/PyUserInput to abstract away the cross-platform differences, though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can accomplish what you want with tkinter, but it's not about not getting focus. I don't think, that other GUI tools will make it any easier.

It's part of operation system, or more precisely window manager to give focus to some window, when it is clicked. So, in case of virtual keyboard:

1. User has focus in text editor (for example).
2. User presses a button on your virtual keyboard.
3. OS/Window manager gives focus to your keyboard window and sends mouse click event to the GUI library (tkinter).
4. Here you need to identify where was the focus before your window got it, i.e. get the text editor window handler somehow.
5. Send the button press event to that window and return focus.
6. Repeat.

You'll use tkinter to draw the keyboard window and handle mouse clicks/touches on virtual keyboard keys. But you'll need to work with OS/Window manager to identify other windows by handlers and send keypress events to them. May be you will be able to prevent focus switch by working with OS/Window manager, but it's not tkinter or other GUI library functionality.